# Axios: Pass data in GET method

Tags: reactjs, parameters, axios

I have created a config file to create an Axios.

```
export const http = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URI,
    responseType: "json",
    timeout: 30000,
    timeoutErrorMessage: "Request Time out",

    headers: {
        withCredentials:true    
    }
})
```

In the other file, I have created helper functions to post, update, and get. Now I am trying to pass data from the body through the get function so far I have following code to get data without passing the body.

```
export const getRequest = (url, is_strict = false) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        http.get(url, {
            headers: getHeaders(is_strict)
        }).then((response) => {
            if(response.status === StatusCodes.OK || response.status === StatusCodes.CREATED){
                resolve(response.data);
            } else {
                reject(response);
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            reject(error);
        })
    })
}
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: There's no need to wrap `http.get` in a `new Promise`, because it already returns a promise (hence `.then`/`.catch`).

Comment: You're trying to include a body in a GET request?  You're doing something with the body of the response to a GET request?  Something else?  It's not really clear to me what specifically you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have a request body in **GET** method. You can use request params instead. Or you can use **POST** method.

Form the [MDN docs for GET](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET),

| property | avaiability |
| --- | --- |
| Request has body | No |
| Request has body | Yes |